# Efficient way to detect strings?

Tags: java, json, deserialization, gson

I am working on a project in which I am making a call to one of my servers using `RestTemplate` which is running a restful service and getting the response back from them.

The response that I will be getting from my server can be either of these error responses (that's all I have for error response) if something has gone wrong -

```
{"warning": "user_id not found", "user_id": some_user_id}
{"error": "user_id for wrong partition", "user_id": some_user_id, "partition": some_partition}
{"error": "missing client id", "client_id":2000}
```

or below successful response (it can be any random json string key can also be different) -

```
{"@data": {"oo":"1205000384","p":"2047935"}
```

1. If I am getting any error response as mentioned above, then I am deserializing it (my bad :( ) so that I can log them as an error with a specific `error` or `warning` I got front the server which can be for example - `user_id not found` or `missing client id`.
2. If it is a successful response then also I am deserializing it which I don't need for my use case as we don't have any POJO and I just need to return the response as it is which I have got from the server.

In my use case, I don't need to deserialize my response string if it is a successful response as we don't have any POJO for that and we are returning the response string as it is which we have got from the server. But just for logging specific error messages (if I am getting error response from the server) I am deserializing it which I am thinking is unnecessary. There might be better solution for my use case.

Below is my Java client which is calling `Callable` task using `future.get` -

```
public class TestingClient implements IClient {

    private ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Override
    public String executeSync(ClientKey keys) {

        String response = null;
        try {

            ClientTask ClientTask = new ClientTask(keys, restTemplate);
            Future<String> future = service.submit(ClientTask);
            response = handle.get(keys.getTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

And now below is my `ClientTask` class  which implements Callable interface. In the call method, I am generating an URL and then hit the server using `RestTemplate` and get the response back -

```
class ClientTask implements Callable<String> {

    private ClientKey cKeys;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public ClientTask(ClientKey cKeys, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.cKeys = cKeys;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {

        // .. some code here
        String url = "some_url";            
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

        String test = checkJSONResponse(response);

        return test;
    }

    private String checkJSONResponse(final String response) throws Exception {

        // may be there are some better way of doing it for my scenario instead of using GSON
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String str = null;
        JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(response, JsonObject.class); // parse it, may be performance issues here/
        if (jsonObject.has("error") || jsonObject.has("warning")) {

        final String error = jsonObject.get("error") != null ? jsonObject.get("error").getAsString() : jsonObject
        .get("warning").getAsString();

        // log specific `error` here using log4j
        str = response;
        } else {
            str = response;
        }

        return str;
    }
}
```

As you can see in my above code we are deserializing the JSON string only to log specific error messages if we are getting any error response back. But for successful response we don't need any deserialization but still we are doing it.

Is there any better way of solving this problem? Because currently I am seeing some performance issues with the GSON deserialization.

The only way I can identify successful response along with error response is with `error` or `warning` in the response so I am thinking of using regular expressions which can identify error or warning as the key in the response string. If they contain error or warning in the response string then extract the specific error or warning message and log it. But not sure whether this will have any performance benefit or not.

Is there any other better way of solving this problem without using GSON deserialization.

Comment: Lot of JSON libs out there for Java, would recommend looking at [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) Lot of subject matter here in this thread too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Comment: I'm curious as to what your "performance issues" are, if not imagined. That aside, you can simply *parse* the JSON using Gson's `JsonParser` class then work with the parse tree objects directly rather than deserializing to a POJO. Regular expressions are *far* more expensive than simple, linear parsing.

Comment: @BrianRoach: So you are saying I should not use `gson.fromJson` method for my use case as it will deserialize it to POJO.. I am not sure about Gson `JsonParser`, can you provide an example basis on my example using JsonParser.. It will make me understand better.

Comment: If `JsonObject` in your code above is a `com.google.gson.JsonObject` and not your own POJO, then all that's being done is parsing the JSON and sticking it in a `Map` inside the object. It is *highly* unlikely there are any "performance issues" to be found there (and highly unlikely you'd be able to do it faster yourself given the tiny size of your JSON)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good practice to use HTTP status codes for your responses (e.g. BAD_REQUEST, NOT_FOUND). Return one of them from the server and then check on the client. It will allow to parse response only if some error code is returned:

```
String result = restTemplate.execute("url", HttpMethod.GET, null, new HttpMessageConverterExtractor<String> {
        @Override
        public MyEntity extractData(ClientHttpResponse response)
        throws IOException {
            String result = super.extractData(response);
            if (response.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
                // parse message and log only for some error code
                JsonObject errorJson = parse(result);
                log.warn("Got {} status error, with message [{}]", response.getStatusCode(), errorJson.get("warning"));
            } 
            return result;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to deserialize to a POJO.

A simple JSON parser such as the one found on [json.org](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) will provide minimal JSON parsing an return a JSONObject that you can query.

I very much doubt that

- you can come up with a faster parsing of your json responses using regular expressions or otherwise, without taking the risk of failing in corner cases
- given the size of your response strings, that the JSON parsing is the performance bottleneck in your code

Unless you have done some serious profiling, I would play safe and follow [the first rule of program optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization)